# D3 - how to give the x axis a non 0 position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want my x axis to be at y = 5.

Is there a proper way to do this?

At the moment I am doing the following:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (chartHeight - margin.top - y(5)) + ")")
```

Which should work, but it feels like a bit of a fudge. Is there a more natural way to set the x axis position using a domain value?

Comment: No. This is the way to do it.